# Why does Apache server return 404 on subfolder, when it was previously working

Tags: ubuntu, php, wordpress, apache2, http-status-code-404

I just installed some new SSL from GoDaddy on my Apache Ubuntu server.

I then restarted via SSH and everything looks good.

The root site (a wordpress install) now loads fine with https.

However, there is another HTML site in the /app directory, which returns 404.

This was previously working.
I've not changed any config files.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does the Apache error log say?

Comment: Not seeing anything in the logs, just getting a 404

Comment: It sounds as though the request might not be reaching your server. Do you see the request in the access log? If the request is reaching your server, then you'll need to post your Apache config here in order for us to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments people.
Turns out the client had moved the site to a different host without telling me, but forgot to take the subfolder with the main site root!

No wonder it was 404.